# saslauthd auth login to postfix meet 454 4.7.0 Temporary authentication failure: generic failure

Tags: postfix, authentication, sasl

when I use cyrus sasl to auth postfix, meet 454 4.7.0 Temporary authentication failure: generic failure.
auth chain  was telnet -> postfix -> sasl -> pam -> mysql
ps:
I found if I start saslauthd with shadow method, testsaslauthd can test ubuntu system login success, but change to pam, it failed, so authentication failure caused by pam ?

1.OS

```
Ubuntu 16.04.03 Gnome
```

2. Software version

```
postfix-3.2.2
cyrus-sasl-2.1.26
Linux-PAM-1.3.0
mariadb-10.2.7
openldap-2.4.45 
openssl-1.1.0f
dovecot-2.2.31
```

all these software was installed by compilied from source code.

3.configure file contents

vim /etc/default/saslauthd

```
START=yes
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="pam"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r"
```

vim /etc/pam.d/smtp

```
auth    required   pam_mysql.so user=mail_admin passwd=password-for-mail_admin host=127.0.0.1 db=mail table=users usercolumn=email passwdcolumn=password crypt=1
account sufficient pam_mysql.so user=mail_admin passwd=password-for-mail_admin host=127.0.0.1 db=mail table=users usercolumn=email passwdcolumn=password crypt=1
```

vim /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: mail_admin
sql_passwd: password-for-mail_admin
sql_database: mail
sql_select: select password from users where email = '%u@%r'
```

vim /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
canceled submission comments
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

and and below at last
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
```

vim /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
compatibility_level = 2
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
#default_privs = nobody
myhostname = localhost
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
#mynetworks_style = subnet
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.3.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24,hash:/etc/postfix/access
#masquerade_domains = mail.example.com www.example.com
#masquerade_exceptions = root
mydestination = example.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
#relay_domains = $mydestination
#relayhost = $isp.com

notify_classes=2bounce, policy, protocol, software, resource
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-3.2.2/html
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-3.2.2/readme
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
shlib_directory = no

smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
#smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/CAcert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
allow_untrusted_routing = no

smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/postfix/sasl
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = example.com
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd

smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_sender_login_maps.cf
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions=check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,permit_mynetworks,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_smtpd_sender_limit.cf,reject_sender_login_mismatch,eermit_sasl_authenticated,permit_auth_destination, reject
#smtpd_client_restrictions = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_smtpd_client_limit.cf,permit_sasl_authenticated
#smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_smtpd_sender_limit.cf,reject_sender_login_mismatch,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = !192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.0/24,192.168.3.0/24
#smtpd_restriction_classes = local_only
#local_only = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/local_domains,reject

smtpd_delay_reject=yes
disable_vrfy_command =yes
#smtpd_helo_restrictions = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_smtpd_client_limit.cf,mysql:/etc/postfixsmtpd_recipient_limitmysql_smtpd_helo_limit.cf
smtpd_helo_required = yes

maximal_queue_lifetime = 6h
queue_run_delay = 3600s

fallback_relay = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_fallbackrelay.cf
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 10

smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=200
smtp_data_done_timeout=3600
smtp_data_init_timeout=3600
smtp_data_xfer_timeout=3600
hopcount_limit = 50
always_add_missing_headers = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450

local_recipient_maps = 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases

virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks 
home_mailbox=Maildir/

message_size_limit = 30720000
mailbox_size_limit = 62222222
bounce_size_limit = 50000

virtual_transport = dovecot
local_transport = dovecot
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

4.log files
saslfinger -s

```
saslfinger - postfix Cyrus sasl configuration Sun Aug 27 19:12:41 CST 2017
version: 1.0.4
mode: server-side SMTP AUTH

-- basics --
Postfix: 3.2.2
System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS \n \l

-- smtpd is linked to --
    libsasl2.so.3 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007f566b162000)

-- active SMTP AUTH and TLS parameters for smtpd --
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = !192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.0/24,192.168.3.0/24
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = example.com
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes


-- listing of /usr/lib/sasl2 --
total 3788
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Aug 27 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 189 root root  20480 Aug 27 16:55 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    684 Aug 27 16:55 libanonymous.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  73088 Aug 27 16:55 libanonymous.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  73088 Aug 27 16:55 libanonymous.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  73088 Aug 27 16:55 libanonymous.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    672 Aug 27 16:55 libcrammd5.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  84752 Aug 27 16:55 libcrammd5.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  84752 Aug 27 16:55 libcrammd5.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  84752 Aug 27 16:55 libcrammd5.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    693 Aug 27 16:55 libdigestmd5.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 218144 Aug 27 16:55 libdigestmd5.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 218144 Aug 27 16:55 libdigestmd5.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 218144 Aug 27 16:55 libdigestmd5.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    704 Aug 27 16:55 libgs2.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 130464 Aug 27 16:55 libgs2.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 130464 Aug 27 16:55 libgs2.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 130464 Aug 27 16:55 libgs2.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    734 Aug 27 16:55 libgssapiv2.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 122640 Aug 27 16:55 libgssapiv2.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 122640 Aug 27 16:55 libgssapiv2.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 122640 Aug 27 16:55 libgssapiv2.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    668 Aug 27 16:55 liblogin.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  76808 Aug 27 16:55 liblogin.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  76808 Aug 27 16:55 liblogin.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  76808 Aug 27 16:55 liblogin.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    657 Aug 27 16:55 libotp.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 205728 Aug 27 16:55 libotp.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 205728 Aug 27 16:55 libotp.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 205728 Aug 27 16:55 libotp.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    668 Aug 27 16:55 libplain.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  76296 Aug 27 16:55 libplain.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  76296 Aug 27 16:55 libplain.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  76296 Aug 27 16:55 libplain.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    669 Aug 27 16:55 libscram.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 148848 Aug 27 16:55 libscram.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 148848 Aug 27 16:55 libscram.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 148848 Aug 27 16:55 libscram.so.3.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    687 Aug 27 16:55 libsql.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 114808 Aug 27 16:55 libsql.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 114808 Aug 27 16:55 libsql.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 114808 Aug 27 16:55 libsql.so.3.0.0

-- listing of /etc/postfix/sasl --
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 19 15:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Aug 27 17:26 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  257 Aug 19 15:31 smtpd.conf




-- content of /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf --
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: --- replaced ---
sql_passwd: --- replaced ---
sql_database: mail
sql_select: select password from users where email = '%u@%r'

-- content of /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf --
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: --- replaced ---
sql_passwd: --- replaced ---
sql_database: mail
sql_select: select password from users where email = '%u@%r'


-- active services in /etc/postfix/master.cf --
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  #-o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  #-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  #-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
devocot    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
   flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}

-- mechanisms on localhost --
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
-- end of saslfinger output --
```

vim /var/log/mail.log

```
Aug 27 17:48:44 tiger postfix/smtpd[17580]: warning: localhost[127.0.0.1]: SASL login authentication failed: generic failure
Aug 27 17:48:44 tiger postfix/smtpd[17580]: > localhost[127.0.0.1]: 454 4.7.0 Temporary authentication failure: generic failure
```

telnet localhost 25

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 localhost ESMTP Postfix
ehlo localhost
250-localhost
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 30720000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
AUTH PLAIN AHRlc3QxQHhpZWRlYWNjLmNvbQBxaDYyODhRSFc=
454 4.7.0 Temporary authentication failure: generic failure
```

5.process status

```
mysql
ps -fe | grep mysql
root     15826     1  0 17:21 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/usr/local/mariadb/etc/my_3306.cnf --basedir=/usr/local/mariadb --datadir=/usr/local/mariadb/data/3306/data/dbdata_raw/data --log-error=/usr/local/mariadb/data/3306/logs/dblogs/mysqld.err --open-files-limit=65535 --pid-file=/usr/local/mariadb/data/3306/prod/mysql.pid --socket=/usr/local/mariadb/data/3306/prod/mysql.sock --port=3306 --user=mysql
mysql    16280 15826  0 17:21 ?        00:00:08 /usr/local/mariadb/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/usr/local/mariadb/etc/my_3306.cnf --basedir=/usr/local/mariadb --datadir=/usr/local/mariadb/data/3306/data/dbdata_raw/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mariadb/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mariadb/data/3306/logs/dblogs/mysqld.err --open-files-limit=65535 --pid-file=/usr/local/mariadb/data/3306/prod/mysql.pid --socket=/usr/local/mariadb/data/3306/prod/mysql.sock --port=3306
root     19029  5101  0 19:16 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql

saslauthd
ps -fe | grep sasl 
root      1408     1  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5
root      1438  1408  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5
root      1439  1408  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5
root      1440  1408  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5
root      1441  1408  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r -n 5

postfix
ps -fe | grep postfix
root      2255     1  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master -w
postfix  16796  2255  0 17:26 ?        00:00:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
postfix  17581  2255  0 17:45 ?        00:00:00 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u
postfix  18865  2255  0 18:58 ?        00:00:00 trivial-rewrite -n rewrite -t unix -u
postfix  18922  2255  0 19:07 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t unix -u
postfix  19034  2255  0 19:17 ?        00:00:00 cleanup -z -t unix -u
root     19043  5101  0 19:18 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postfix

dovecot
ps -fe | grep dovecot
root      1391     1  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dovecot
dovecot   1392  1391  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 dovecot/anvil
root      1393  1391  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 dovecot/log
root      1395  1391  0 16:07 ?        00:00:00 dovecot/config
```

thanks~

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed it by updating libpam-mysql, since the package version in ubuntu 16.04 was too low.

Manual download libpam-mysql from https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libpam-mysql, and install it.

Be aware that this version is not tested in 16.04 and therefore not recommended for production use.

Comment: How did you do that? Please [edit] your answer to add some detail that will help others solve the same problem